# Must I download image from Firebase to display it?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I am using Flutter and Firebase. I have managed to upload user profile photos to teh Firebase Storage using a scheme like this:

users/userid.png

So far, whenever I need to display the user profile image, I have to download it first to local; like

```
final String fileName = uid + ".png";

Directory appDocDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
final File file = File('$appDocPath/$fileName');
// clears the file
file.writeAsStringSync("");
final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('users/' + fileName);

final StorageFileDownloadTask downloadTask = ref.writeToFile(file);

final int byteNumber = (await downloadTask.future).totalByteCount;

print("byteNumber : ${byteNumber}");
    } catch(e) {
      return null;
    }
```

However, I was wondering if I can just skip the step and just use NetworkImage() function like:

```
final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('users/' + user.uid + ".png");
String downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL();

downloadURL = Uri.decodeFull(downloadURL.toString());
print("FB Storage URL: $downloadURL");


return new NetworkImage(downloadURL);
```

It doesn't work and throws an exception.

What I am trying to do; is it possible?

Comment: Please add the exception.

Answer (score 3):

The data for an image that you want to display will always have to be read into the app that you want to display it in. But you don't necessarily have to handle that downloading yourself as you do now.

Any file in Firebase Storage has a so-called download URL. Anyone who has this URL can read the file, without having to use the Firebase Storage SDK. This is pretty much how most of the images from the internet are, so there are lots of libraries that can handle such an image URL.

For example, the [Flutter cookbook has a section on displaying images from the internet](https://flutter.io/cookbook/images/network-image/), which shows that the `Image` widget can display an image from a URL like this:

```
Image.network(
  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/_includes/code/layout/lakes/images/lake.jpg',
)
```

Where this uses an image from Github, you can also use a download URL from Firebase Storage.

Most apps store the download URL of the files in their database when they upload the file. If you don't have the download URL, but only the path, you can get the download URL with:

```
final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('users/' + fileName);
final Uri downloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadUrl();
```

*I'm not a Flutter expert, so there might be some problems in that code snippet.*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out I was getting errors.
I was converting the URI to String and using it in NetworkImage.
When I remove the .ToString() from the URI, it works.